# Nagios Check_hpjd giving me problems!

Tags: snmp, nagios

When I run the following

> [root@host plugins]# ./check_hpjd -H
>   printer1.mydomain.com   : Timeout from
>   host printer1.mydomain.com

I have Net-snmp installed on my system, I noted that i didn't have net-snmp-utils installed, and then I was able to run

> [root@host plugins]# snmpwalk -Os -c
>   public -v 1 printer1.mydomain.com system
>
> sysDescr.0 = STRING: HP ETHERNET
>   MULTI-ENVIRONMENT sysObjectID.0 = OID:
>   enterprises.11.2.3.9.1
>   sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks:
>   (325408663) 37 days, 15:54:46.63
>   sysContact.0 = STRING: sysName.0 =
>   STRING: printer1 sysLocation.0 =
>   STRING: sysServices.0 = INTEGER: 72

So I know that the printer is working as expected, (as far as SNMP is 
concerned). But when I run

> [root@host plugins]# ./check_hpjd -H
>   printer1.mydomain.com -C public Error
>   in packet ()

I get this error - From what I've tried so far, I know my host can 
communicate via SNMP, I know the printer responds via SNMP, so I guess 
I'm left to look at the plug-in, which I will be checking up on.  I'm 
new to SNMP, I am investigating this with my good friend Google search, 
but I am on a learning curve here, so please forgive my questions if 
they sound stupid,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My printer is not 100% JetDirect compatible! *GRRRRRR!*